# eks:cloud-controller-manager cluster role in EKS/K8s

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I noticed that a new cluster role - "eks:cloud-controller-manager"  appeared in our EKS cluster. we never created it.I tried to find origin/creation of this cluster role but not able to find it.

any idea what does "eks:cloud-controller-manager" cluster role does in EKS cluster?

`$ kubectl get clusterrole eks:cloud-controller-manager -o yaml`

````
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"ClusterRole","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"eks:cloud-controller-manager"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["events"],"verbs":["create","patch","update"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["nodes"],"verbs":["*"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["nodes/status"],"verbs":["patch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["services"],"verbs":["list","patch","update","watch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["services/status"],"verbs":["list","patch","update","watch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["serviceaccounts"],"verbs":["create","get"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["persistentvolumes"],"verbs":["get","list","update","watch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["endpoints"],"verbs":["create","get","list","watch","update"]},{"apiGroups":["coordination.k8s.io"],"resources":["leases"],"verbs":["create","get","list","watch","update"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["serviceaccounts/token"],"verbs":["create"]}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-02T00:25:52Z"
  name: eks:cloud-controller-manager
  resourceVersion: "762242250"
  uid: 34e568bb-20b5-4c33-8a7b-fcd081ae0a28
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - serviceaccounts/token
  verbs:
  - create```

I tried to find this object in our Gitops repo but do not find it.
````

Answer (score 1):

This role is created by AWS when you provision the cluster. This role is for the AWS [cloud-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/) to integrate AWS services (eg. CLB/NLB, EBS) with Kubernetes. You will also find other roles like eks:fargate-manager to integrate with Fargate.